# How to pass javascript variable to ajax 'data' attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am tying to pass a javascript variable as an ajax paramater but it is being sent as null. Simply passing 'host' gives 'host' itself which isn't what is desired

```
var host = "some value"
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/Main/GetData/',
  data: '{'
  hostname '=' + host '}',
  dataType: 'json',

  success: function(json) {
    var data = json;
  },
}); //ajax
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
data: {'hostname' : host},
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data as an `object`, using key you can access the value of the variable on the server side.

USE:

```
var host = "some value"
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/Main/GetData/',
  data: {
    "hostname": host
  },
  dataType: 'json',

  success: function(json) {
    var data = json;
  },
}); //ajax
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send data as a string make use of `JSON.stringify()`

```
dataToSend = JSON.stringify({ "hostname": host });
```

And in your AJAX

```
data : dataToSend
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel the problem is you have made the wrong JSON data format.
the correct JSON format should be like this:`{key:value}`
Give an eg. here:

```
"employees": [
  { "firstName":"Bill" , "lastName":"Gates" },
  { "firstName":"George" , "lastName":"Bush" },
  { "firstName":"Thomas" , "lastName":"Carter" }
]
```

ex:the employee contains 3 elements

Wish can make some help :)